# ASP.NET Core Custom Role Based Authorization (Custom User.IsInRole)?

Tags: asp.net, authorization, .net-core, coreclr

I am using a postgres Database through a library called Marten with a .NET app, I have a custom `IUserLoginStore` which manages retrieving the user and its roles. This seems to be working correctly but I am have an issue with setting up authorization.

I am using authentication through google and it is working fine:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
```

This action throws an access denied issue:

```
[HttpPost()]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public JsonResult SubmitArticle([FromBody] ArticleInputModel input) {...}
```

**I have dug into the Authorization code and the problem seems to be with the default `ClaimsPrincipal` code:**

```
public virtual bool IsInRole(string role)
{
  return false;
}
```

Should I implement my own version of `ClaimsPrinciple` and override the `IsInRole`, and if I do how do I get this back into the app?

```
private static void ConfigureSecurity(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddUserValidator<UserValidator>()
        .AddUserStore<MartenUserStore>()
        .AddRoleStore<MartenRoleStore>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

Comment: Posted about this in github as well, awaiting response: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright figured it out after a large amount of digging, In my case the `MartenRoleStore` was implementing `IUserLoginStore` it also needed to implement `IUserRoleStore` which has `GetRolesAsync` and `IsInRoleAsync`. **(This is very important it has to be the exact same class you used for .AddUserStore<>();)**

This is the code that I found that caused the issue:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs#L258

This is what makes it work:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L96

Comment: Links are broken :(

Comment: I am going to be honest, I haven't done .NET for like a year now, I think those links were pointing to, but have no clue:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Core/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L140 

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L1343